# num_tol_term in PeptideProphet result

Tags: bioinformatics

What is the meaning of the num_tol_term attribute in a PeptideProphet (pep.xml) search_hit?

```
<search_hit hit_rank="1" peptide="DATDDFEDVGHSTTAR" peptide_prev_aa="K" peptide_next_aa="A" protein="Traes_5AL_64120ED6B.1" 
    num_tot_proteins="4" num_matched_ions="9" tot_num_ions="30" calc_neutral_pep_mass="1735.7364" massdiff="-0.0269" 
    num_tol_term="2" num_missed_cleavages="0" is_rejected="0" protein_descr="| AT2G32720.1 | member of Cytochromes b5">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the PeptideProphet paper: **number of tryptic
termini (NTT)**

> This number, which can be 0, 1, or 2, measures how
>   many of the peptide termini, on the basis of amino acid sequence,
>   are consistent with cleavage by trypsin.